# Hang up while dialing a phone number after firts bip using using ISDN modem (C#)

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, visual-c++, tapi

I want to hang up after modem finish dialing a phone number.
I can track when modem start dial and when it disconnect. But I can't track dial finished.
I use TAPI for it. I tried C# and C++. But I don't know how to manage it.

Comment: People still use modems?

Comment: If he wants to hang up after the first beep then he's not using it for fax or data.

Comment: Yes, I'm not using it for fax or data. I'm using it to get know if phone number is valid (or exist).

Answer (score 2):

When a modem is dialing, it's normally just sitting there waiting for the other end to answer.    TAPI can tell you when the dialing starts (because it sends the command to dial) and when the hangup occurs (because the modem reports "NO CARRIER"), and it can tell you when the other *modem* answers (because then the modem reports that it's connected), but the modem doesn't say when it's done dialing.  (So-called "winmodems" *might* be able to do this, as they're run more by the driver than the hardware in the modem.  But it's not something you can really rely on.)

This means that the only way you can really know is to have a modem that can feed the sound on the phone line back in through a mic or line-in or something (which also isn't exactly universal on a modem), and having some software listen for the touch tones and report when it hears a pause.

Comment: I hope that I didn't know smth or didn't read. I'm searching about getting media from modem and do smth with it. I was hoping to not do this.

Comment: I'm looking over the TAPI docs on MSDN.  there's an "in progress" call state, but that basically just means "dialing and waiting for an answer".   So yeah, you're probably going to have to listen in or something (unless you have some way to bypass TAPI and talk directly to your modem, and have a modem that will tell you more details about the call state).

Comment: In progress - it's when call in progress, when i'm already connected and I'm using phone for talking or sending/recieving data or smth else.